# how do electrical arcs occur?

Tags: high-voltage, amperage, arc

I was under the impression that arcs form due to high voltage, that the breakdown of air was typically 3 million volts per meter. However, arc furnaces typically use low voltages, around 30 to 40 volts, and high amperages, usually a couple hundred amps. Do arcs form from high amperages too, or do they form from high power or what?

Comment: How many meters is the arc of your arc furnace when it forms?

Comment: [Thermionic emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission)

Comment: Is there a striking voltage then a running voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [Paschen's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law)

> Paschen's law is an equation that gives the breakdown voltage, that
>   is, the voltage necessary to start a discharge or electric arc,
>   between two electrodes in a gas as a function of pressure and gap
>   length.[2][3] It is named after Friedrich Paschen who discovered it
>   empirically in 1889.[4]
>
> Paschen studied the breakdown voltage of various gases between
>   parallel metal plates as the gas pressure and gap distance were
>   varied:
>
> With a constant gap length, the voltage necessary to arc across the
>   gap decreased as the pressure was reduced and then increased
>   gradually, exceeding its original value. With a constant pressure, the
>   voltage needed to cause an arc reduced as the gap size was reduced but
>   only to a point. As the gap was reduced further, the voltage required
>   to cause an arc began to rise and again exceeded its original value.
>   For a given gas, the voltage is a function only of the product of the
>   pressure and gap length.[2][3] The curve he found of voltage versus
>   the pressure-gap length product (right) is called Paschen's curve. He
>   found an equation that fit these curves, which is now called Paschen's
>   law.[3]

Basically, once air ionizes is becomes quite a good conductor. Passing a high current through it keeps it ionized.

Answer (score 4):

You can read about arc furnaces [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc_furnace). The first thing you might notice is that your description only applies to small furnaces.

> A mid-sized modern steelmaking furnace would have a transformer rated
>   about 60,000,000 volt-amperes (60 MVA), with a secondary voltage
>   between 400 and 900 volts and a secondary current in excess of 44,000
>   amperes.

However, even 400 to 900 volts is not enough to produce an arc over any reasonable distance, so your question remains valid. And the article supplies the answer:

> The electrodes are lowered onto the scrap, an arc is struck

In other words, the electrodes make direct contact with the metal to be melted, so voltage is pretty much irrelevant as long as it produces adequate current. In fact,

> Lower voltages are selected for this first part of the operation to
>   protect the roof and walls from excessive heat and damage from the
>   arcs. Once the electrodes have reached the heavy melt at the base of
>   the furnace and the arcs are shielded by the scrap, the voltage can be
>   increased and the electrodes raised slightly, lengthening the arcs and
>   increasing power to the melt.

Answer (score 2):

Arcs require high voltage to *start*.  The breakdown voltage of air varies considerably with humidity and other factors, but figure roughly 1 kV per mm.

However, that's only to start the arc.  The gasses in the air become a plasma, which conducts electricity much much better than regular air.  As a result, it takes much less voltage to *sustain* the arc.  This is why the voltage across the arc can be low, like a few tens of volts or even less, as long as sufficient current continues to flow to keep maintain the plasma.  Basically, enough power needs to be put into the arc to balance the losses due to convection and radiation.